# Why shows Git/Gitlab a wrong username on account verification in Terminal?

Tags: macos, ssh, git, gitlab

Environment:

- macOS Monterey MacBook Air M1
- OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
- iTerm2

I try to get my SSH connection to work.
After creating a new SSH key file for GitLab and adding it on gitlab.com I do:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.account.in.ssh-config
```

The answer is

```
Welcome to GitLab, @WrongUsername!
```

The wrong username is a user of my private GitLab account. I've checked home directory - there is no global setting in `~/.gitconfig` with an username.

Comment: Why not use `ssh -vv` to see what it does and why it apparently picks the wrong key.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the SSH key to the directory of the project has worked.

With the suggestion of @Daniel B (thank you very much) I was able to debug with:

```
ssh -vv git@gitlab.account.in.ssh-config
```

After that I've done in the project directory:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<private key>
```

So after doing again:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.account.in.ssh-config
```

it shows the correct user now.